# Firebase creates new user if login fails

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my firebase project, whenever a user attempts to login, but it does not exists in the users list, firebase creates one with the credentials of this login.

Is there a way to tell Firebase to ignore users that are not on the projects users list?

It only happens when using providers, such as gmail.

Here is my android code:

```
private void googleSignIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
        //loginWithToken(mEmail, "", account.getIdToken());

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.

    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());

    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle");
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        user.getIdToken(true)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, task.getResult().getToken());
                                            loginWithToken(mEmail, mPassword, task.getResult().getToken());
                                        } else {
                                            loginError();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        /*Snackbar.make(mBinding.mainLayout, "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null); */
                    }
                }
            });
}


  private void loginWithToken(String email, String password, String idToken) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loginwithtoken");
    try {
        ws.connectToken(getApplicationContext(), TAG, idToken);
        
       
        
        finish();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        ;
        loginError();
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase Auth will not create a user account unless you write code to do so.  Without seeing your code, there's not much to say.

Comment: It looks like the sign in activity is doing the work of creating the account.

Comment: @DougStevenson where?

Comment: startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

Comment: I'm following the firebase tutorial. How can  I fix this?